# Is solving $m^3 = k*n + c$ hard?

Tags: encryption, rsa

Given the equation 
$$m^3 = k\cdot n + c$$
I know $n$ and $c$, and I need to find $k$, so that $m$ is a natural number. $n$ and $c$ are large numbers, so i can't use bruteforce.

How can you find a solution?

Comment: $k = (m^3-c)/n$

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, because other than the specific reason the question was being asked ("to crack a cipher"), there's nothing inherently wrong in asking "is this a hard problem?".  However, it may be better suited to math.stackexchange.  On the third hand, I would further note that an Oracle that can solve the analogous problem $m^2 = kn + c$, known $n, c$, find $k$, can be used to efficiently factor, and so it would appear to be unlikely that there's an easy solution in the $m^3$ case.

Comment: I changed the title and restructured the question a little, because it has the potential for a good question (in my opinion; even if the answer might be negative, as poncho pointed out).

Comment: Do you know the factorization of $n$?

Comment: The question does not state that $m$ and/or $k$ are large. If they are small it can be solved.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is equivalent to solving $m^3 \equiv c \pmod n$. This corresponds to breaking RSA for $e=3$. We know no efficient way for doing that without factoring $n$.

If you know the factors of $n$ you can compute the private exponent $d$ as $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ using the extended euclidean algorithm and then compute $m$ as $c^d$.

Comment: Computations are not in (mod n). If yes, how  can we find $k$?

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani Once you know $m$ you can simply compute $k = (m^3-c)/n$ using integers and no modular reduction. If you correctly computed $m$ this division will have no remainder.

Comment: Both $m$ and $k$ are unknown.

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani Yes. But you can first solve for $m^3 \equiv c \pmod n$ for $m$ (though that requires factoring $n$ in the process and is thus infeasible for many large $n$) and then in a second step simply compute $k$ via integer division.